# Access the DOM element of a drop down

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dropdown

I have a drop down list which I use to allow the user to establish the parameters of a query to the back end.

Then the user will click a button and I will access the values the user set in the drop downs, to call the back end endpoint.

Right now Im having a ton of trouble accessing the value selected. This is my drop down :

```
<div className="wrappers">

<div className="timeFrameLabel label">Time Frame: </div>  
<select ref="timeFrame" className="timeFrameDropdown dropdown">
   <option>1m</option>
   <option>5m</option>
   <option>15m</option>
   <option>30m</option>
   <option>1h</option>
   <option>4h</option>
   <option>1d</option>
</select> 
</div>
```

The button looks like this:

```
<Button className="goButton" onClick={this.getBacktestData}>
                Get Data
</Button>
```

Finally the onClick method is as follows:

```
getBacktestData = async() => {
        const { 
            symbol,
            binSize,
            startTime,
            endTime,
        } = this.state;
        var quantity = document.querySelector(".quantityDropdown select")[document.querySelector(".quantityDropdown select").selectedIndex].innerHTML;

        console.log(this.refs.asset.select)
        console.log(this.refs.timeFrame)
        console.log(this.refs.amount)


        return await fetch("http://localhost:3001/backtest/getdata", {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({symbol:symbol, binSize: binSize, startTime:startTime, endTime:endTime}), // data can be `string` or {object}!
            headers:{
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(response => console.log(response))
        .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
    }
```

The desired outcome would be to be able to access and console.log() the selected drop down element.

Any help or tips are more than welcomed.

Comment: Just curious, is there a reason you're trying to access the inner HTML of the dropdown elements versus using their value? This is the more idiomatic way to do it: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#the-select-tag

Comment: using the value would work  even better :). Still no idea how I would proceed on that case, any pointers? @Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the idiomatic way to access `select` values without having to muck around with the DOM.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { selected: null };
  }

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({ selected: e.target.value });
  };

  getBacktestData = async () => {
    const { selected } = this.state;
    // Do something with the selected value
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        Selected: {this.state.selected}
        <select value={this.state.selected} onChange={this.handleChange}>
          <option value="1m">1m</option>
          <option value="5m">5m</option>
          <option value="15m">15m</option>
          <option value="30m">30m</option>
          <option value="1h">1h</option>
          <option value="4h">4h</option>
          <option vlaue="1d">1d</option>
        </select>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could assign the value to the state by first declaring a constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
      timeFrame: ""
   }
}
```

And then declaring an input handler to assign the value to the state:

```
handleInputChange(event) {
   var value = event.target.value;
   var name = event.target.name;
   this.setState({
      [name]: value
   })
}
```

The input handler will use the name attribute on the input field to reference the state, therefore the name attribute on the input should remain consistent with whatever you are calling it in state so your select would then change to:

```
<select ref="timeFrame" name="timeFrame" className="timeFrameDropdown dropdown" onChange={this.handleInputChange.bind(this)} value={this.state.timeFrame}>
   <option value="1m">1m</option>
   <option value="5m">5m</option>
   <option value="15m">15m</option>
   <option value="30m">30m</option>
   <option value="1h">1h</option>
   <option value="4h">4h</option>
   <option value="1d">1d</option>
</select>
```

Now when the user selects a value it will get assigned to the state and in your submit function you can now access it by calling

```
   var timeFrame = this.state.timeFrame;
   console.log("Time Frame: ", timeFrame); //check to see your value
```